# mod_wsgi does not find environment variable in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have some usernames, passwords and other configurations setup in the environment variables of an ec2 instance. I have created a virtualenv setup and active where I run my django server. In the settings file of that django server I access the environment variables as os.environ['variable'].

Outside the virtualenv the site could access those variables fine. When I run printenv, I see all the variables and the values.

However, the server cannot find them and is throwing key errors as a result when I call os.environ on them.

setup = ec2 instance - mod_wsgi - nginx - apache

**UPDATE**
This started working by setting the variables in django.wsgi in the following way.

```
os.environ['SQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
```

That alone stopped working once I upgraded to the new ec2 hardware. I am not sure how that was related.

Now, what worked finally was setting the variables individually using SetEnv in the apache config file. Still not optimal because I have to keep the config file checked out on the production machine but it unblocks me.

```
SetEnv SQL_PASSWORD password
```

Comment: Do you have the virtualenv active when you run printenv?

Comment: Yes it is active as far as I can tell.

Comment: The shell prompt says so.

Comment: Can you get any environment variables? Please show a minimal extract which triggers the problem (at least show your imports and the line giving the error). Also, I assume you're running django with virtualenv active.

Comment: might want to look at: `print os.environ`

Comment: What are you serving your django app with and where are you setting those environment variables from? It sounds more like a user profile configuration issue and whether your server can access such variables.

Comment: I am not too familiar with this stuff but the setup is mod_wsgi, nginx and apache. I am wondering if that is not passing the variables. Print os environ gives me all the variables and their values.

Comment: What fixed it was hard-coding thevariables in the django.wsgi file. os.environ['variable'] = 'value'. I am not fond of this solution because I have to keep some information in code which I cannot checkin, however, it is a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

I use nginx and uwsgi on Ec2 and have a chef recipe that builds out my servers. To solve this problem, in chef I have roles that contain credentials not stored in the app's repo.

file at `/home/user/web/site/environment` that chef creates based on roles.

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=databasename
MYSQL_USER=databaseuser
MYSQL_PASSWORD=databasepassword
MYSQL_HOST=databaseip
MYSQL_PORT=3306

REDIS_HOST=redishost
REDIS_PASSWORD=redispassword
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_DB=0

MEDIA_ROOT=/home/user/web/site/media
STATIC_ROOT=/home/user/web/site/static
```

at the beginning of my production/staging/etc settings file I have the following block to read the environment file

```
import os, re

try:
    dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # my environment file is always in the same place relative to my project's settings file
    env_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dirname, '..', '..', '..', '..', 'environment'))
    with open(env_path) as f:
        content = f.read()

        for line in content.splitlines():
            m1 = re.match(r'\A([A-Za-z_0-9]+)=(.*)\Z', line)
            if m1:
                key, val = m1.group(1), m1.group(2)
                m2 = re.match(r"\A'(.*)'\Z", val)
                if m2:
                    val = m2.group(1)
                m3 = re.match(r'\A"(.*)"\Z', val)
                if m3:
                    val = re.sub(r'\\(.)', r'\1', m3.group(1))
                os.environ.setdefault(key, val)
except IOError:
    pass
```

Voila, settings are source controlled in a separately managed repo (chef's) and loaded into the app. This may not be the *BEST* way, but it is fairly secure b/c of how permissions are locked down on the chef repo and the target servers and easy to deploy.

Comment: Seems possible but there should be a better way to do this. I have all the passwords set in the environment when I check them using python. Why does mod_wsgi not load those?

Comment: which user's environment are they in? your ssh user's, or your apache user's? Apache is running as apache (probably? im a uwsgi man)

Comment: the .bash_profile for which user? apache I believe runs as its own user named apache. if you are setting it in your ssh user's .bash_profile then its not going to be loaded into the environment for your app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as

Comment: It is the same user. Perhaps I need to do this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#passenv. However, I am not sure what file I should passing the environment variables in: PassEnv MY_VAR

Comment: that sounds promising. when it gets into the nitty gritty of apache I can't help too much - its not something I get into too often.